# How to update/add data to JSON file using AngularJS and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>       
        <title>Angular</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">  
      <p>Price: <input type="number" ng-model="itemAmount" placeholder="Enter the price"/> </p>
      <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="itemName" placeholder="Enter the itemName"/>  </p>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="addItem()">Submit</button>

    </body >
    </html>
```

Controller

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope) {

      $scope.items = [];
      $scope.addItem = function() {

        $scope.items.push({
          amount: $scope.itemAmount,
          name: $scope.itemName
        });

        var data = JSON.stringify($scope.items);

        $http({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080',
          method: "POST",
          data: data,
          header: 'Content-Type: application/json'
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        });

        // Clear input fields after push
        $scope.itemAmount = "";
        $scope.itemName = "";
      };
    });
```

JSON file

```
 {"items":[]}
```

NodeJS code

```
 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var fs = require('fs');

    app.use(express.static('static'));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    app.post('/', function (req, res) {
      fs.writeFile(__dirname+"/post.json", req.body, function(err) {
        if(err) {
           return console.log(err);
        }

       res.send('The file was saved!');
      }); 
    });

    app.listen(8080, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
    });
```

I used the code which has already been asked in one of the question. Having said that, i wanted to update the json file which is empty initially with only curly braces using the nodejs and angularjs code. When i enter in the input fields and click on submit, the data should get updated in json file. There is something wrong in my controller code, i guess. please help!!
For example, if i enter 23 in the price field and "apples" in name filed, my json file should get updated to:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "amount": 23,
    "name": "apples"
  }]
}
```

Error shown in the console:

```
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Comment: stringify the `req.body`. try `fs.writeFile(__dirname+"/post.json", JSON.stringify(req.body), 'utf8', function(err) {..` also if you want to keep the existing stuff in `post.json` use `fs.appendFile(`

Comment: I have already stringified the data in controller code

Comment: at the server side `express` will reconverts that to `object` (for easy usage). so you have to `stringify` again if you want to write that to a file.

Comment: Not working. I added the error shown in the console. Can you make out anything from it?